# How to use DevExpress DataGrid's VirtualScrolling feature in Blazor with a lot of data?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, blazor

I have a razor page that is using the DevExpress' DataGrid component.

I would like to use the [virtual scrolling feature](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/GridPagingAndScrolling#VirtualScrolling) because the source of data is remote and contains a lot of rows but I can't seem to make the virtual scrolling work. It loads the first x rows and I do not know how get any notifications asking to retrieve more data from the remote source.

```
@using DevExpress.Blazor

@inject IEditorViewModel m_editorViewModel;

<h3>Editor</h3>

<DxDataGrid Data="@m_editorViewModel.Records"
            DataNavigationMode="DataGridNavigationMode.VirtualScrolling"
            VerticalScrollBarMode="@ScrollBarMode.Auto"
            VerticalScrollableHeight="300"
            >
   ...
</DxDataGrid>

@code {

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        return m_editorViewModel.LoadAsync();
    }
}

public interface IEditorViewModel
{
     List<Record> Records { get; }

     Task LoadAsync();
}
```

**Question**

How can I use DevExpress DataGrid's VirtualScrolling feature in Blazor when I have a lot of data? I do not understand what is the mechanism used to trigger the data source to load the next batch of results.

Comment: On devexpress blazor [demo site](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/GridPagingAndScrolling#VirtualScrolling) there is overview & explanation of the feature.  Generally I raise support ticket [here](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/list) for additional queries. usually they answers within 1 day

Comment: @Ashish This is the exact same page that I used to get information. However I did not see what is the mechanism that triggers the data source to load the next batch of results.

Comment: In that case consider directly asking to devexpress support.